# add a value to login form joomla 2.5

Tags: forms, authentication, joomla, joomla2.5

I'm trying to add a value to the input boxes of Joomla front end login.
I call the login module by adding it to a menu. So it's not a module on a specific page it's just a page. (website.com/login)

Now I've found a lot off files what has to do with the login. And found file: "\components\com_users\models\forms\login.xml" and changed:

```
$   <field name="username" type="text"
        class="validate-username"
        filter="username"
        label="COM_USERS_LOGIN_USERNAME_LABEL"
        style="25"
        validate="username"
    />
```

to

```
$   <field name="username" type="text"
        class="validate-username"
        filter="username"
        label="COM_USERS_LOGIN_USERNAME_LABEL"
        value="Gebruikersnaam"
        validate="username"
    />
```

But style is gone and value did not appear. (Now I think this file is imported.)

How do I add value to my login input's? They are now empty. (in the line is standing: value="")
I think something overrides it but can't see what.

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you are looking for `default="Gebrui..."` instead of value ?

http://docs.joomla.org/Text_form_field_type